# Is Heap Spraying only valid for browser applications?

Tags: web-browser, javascript, heapspray

Since heap spraying takes advantage of javascript's predictability in allocating heap chunks, does this mean that heap spraying only works for browser applications and not other usual applications?

Comment: Any language, protocol, etc that accept data, which contains the vulnerabilities, will subject to this exploit.

Comment: JIT spraying (a type of heap spraying) is more common in the context of browsers, though even it isn't unique to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, heap spray can be used for any exploit that needs heap data to be aligned a certain way. Example include the ExternalBlue exploit that targets SMB. It heaps sprays a bunch of SMB objects to align the memory, so that the right objects get corrupted.